# Transform a character variable into a binary presence/absence matrix using R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data with character, I want to transform a data into presence absence data form, if any character like variable is present, I want to make it as one, if there is empty, i want to change as 0.

```
df <- data.frame(
  A = c("G1","G2","G3","G4","G5","G6","G7","G8","G9","G10"),
  B = c("A",  "",  "A", "", "G", "B", "C",  "",  "",   "" ),
  C = c("B",  "",  "Z", "", "",   "", "",  'B',  "C",  "" ),
  D = c("Z", "D",  "",  "", "",   "", "",   "",  "",   "D"),
  E = c("A", "E",  "B", "A","",   "", "",   "",  "",    "")
)
```

output look like this

```
df <- data.frame(
      A = c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G4", "G5","G6","G7", "G8", "G9","G10"),
      B = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
      C = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0),
      D = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
      E = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

With base R you can replace the data.frame in place

```
df[, -1] <- lapply(df[, -1], function(x) ifelse(nchar(x)>0,1,0))
```

Or with `dplyr` you can mutate the data.frame to create a new one

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(-A, ~if_else(nchar(.)>0, 1, 0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `nzchar` as well

```
> df[-1] <- +nzchar(as.matrix(df[-1]))

> df
     A B C D E
1   G1 1 1 1 1
2   G2 0 0 1 1
3   G3 1 1 0 1
4   G4 0 0 0 1
5   G5 1 0 0 0
6   G6 1 0 0 0
7   G7 1 0 0 0
8   G8 0 1 0 0
9   G9 0 1 0 0
10 G10 0 0 1 0
```